# Ambiguity in naming haloalkanes

Tags: organic-chemistry

My question in quite simple why a compound such as chloro-ethane is called as such why is if not chloro-ethyl??

Since it is a hydrogen short.

Comment: Holoalkanes...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chloroethane is ethane with 1 hydrogen replaced by chlorine. So it is substituted ethane.

$$\ce{CH3-CH2Cl}$$

1-Chloroethyl or 2-Chloroethyl  is **ethyl** with 1 hydrogen replaced by chlorine. So it is substituted ethyl radical, standalone or bound to a larger molecular structure.

$$\ce{CH3-CHCl.}$$

or

$$\ce{CH2Cl-CH2.}$$